# nornir.close_connections() is not disconnecting session from Palo Alto

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming

need to make sure the connection made during nornir /netmiko call the the palo altos gets disconnected after command run.

I need to use filter to decide which host to run the command on. I am using nornir.close_connection(filter.invertory.hosts)

```py
nr=InitNornir()
fw=nr.filter(name='vc01pan001')

outcome=fw.run(
    netmiko_send_command,
    use_timing=True,
    command_string='show admins',
    num_workers=5,
)

nr.close_connections(fw.inventory.hosts)
```

On the palo alto, I still see the connection for this session.
EXPECTED : session disconnects after running `outcome`.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you specifying in your Nornir inventory?

Here is what Netmiko does on the disconnect() call for PAN-OS.

https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/netmiko/paloalto/paloalto_panos.py#L169

It looks like possibly another "exit" is required for PAN-OS. But if that is the case please test it and then submit a PR or an issue to the Netmiko github repository.